# How to disconnect PST file from Outlook using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, outlook, pst

I'm trying to write a script to disconnect PSTs files from Outlook.

I've been trying with something like this:

```powershell
$Outlook = new-object -com outlook.application 
$Namespace = $Outlook.getNamespace("MAPI")

$PSTtoDelete = "c:\test\pst.pst"

$Namespace.RemoveStore($PSTtoDelete)
```

I get the following error:

> "Cannot Find overload for "RemoveStore" and the argument count "1".

I also tried a different solution with this (found here http://www.mikepfeiffer.net/2013/04/how-to-test-outlook-pst-personal-folder-file-access-with-powershell/) :

```powershell
$namespace.GetType().InvokeMember('RemoveStore',[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,$null,$namespace,($PSTFolder))
```

I took a look to the [technect documentations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864232%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and if I understand properly the RemoveStore Method expects a Folder.

If anyone would be able to give me a hint on this one that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your link the script expects *Name* of the attached PST, not the path. Try this:

```powershell
$Outlook = new-object -com outlook.application 
$Namespace = $Outlook.getNamespace("MAPI")

$PSTtoDelete = "c:\test\pst.pst"
$PST = $namespace.Stores | ? {$_.FilePath -eq $PSTtoDelete}
$PSTRoot = $PST.GetRootFolder()


$PSTFolder = $namespace.Folders.Item($PSTRoot.Name)
$namespace.GetType().InvokeMember('RemoveStore',[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,$null,$namespace,($PSTFolder))
```

Comment: if PST has the same name as the main account, $PSTFolder is the wrong object. RemoveStore does not work.

Comment: RemoveStore does not expect a name (string). It expects an instance of the Store object.

Answer (score 1):

To remove ALL .pst files:

```powershell
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Namespace = $Outlook.getNamespace("MAPI")

$all_psts = $Namespace.Stores | Where-Object {($_.ExchangeStoreType -eq '3') -and ($_.FilePath -like '*.pst') -and ($_.IsDataFileStore -eq $true)}

ForEach ($pst in $all_psts){
    $Outlook.Session.RemoveStore($pst.GetRootFolder())
}
```