# Outlook Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have been doing some digging and trying to find a way to remove a PST from Outlook with a script. I don't entirely know how to script but am trying to learn. I found this old Stackoverflow but I am unsure how to actually enter the information I need into it.

[How to disconnect PST file from Outlook using Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058514/how-to-disconnect-pst-file-from-outlook-using-powershell?newreg=cb12fd9338594856a32074535e72eccc)

The script in question is below.

```
$Outlook = new-object -com outlook.application 
$Namespace = $Outlook.getNamespace("MAPI")

$PSTtoDelete = "c:\test\pst.pst"
$PST = $namespace.Stores | ? {$_.FilePath -eq $PSTtoDelete}
$PSTRoot = $PST.GetRootFolder()


$PSTFolder = $namespace.Folders.Item($PSTRoot.Name)
$namespace.GetType().InvokeMember('RemoveStore',[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,$null,$namespace,($PSTFolder))
```

I understand the third line, where to enter the file path to the PST itself but I am not sure what to enter for the rest of the lines.

I know this is a total newbie question, but any help would be super appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: have you run it? did you get errors? what do you not understand?

Comment: So aside from the "c:\test\pst.pst" is there any other portion of this script that needs to be pointed at anything for it to work?

Comment: no clue. Doesnt look like it ...run and see what errors you get...thats how we start to debug....

Comment: So when I try to run it I get a very quick flash of an error.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/L3FNL0MhgrKp6UA83

Comment: Do you have any scripting experience? (Not trying to be sarcastic) just trying to see what im working with

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function i just wrote hope it helps

```
function Remove-OutlookStore($StoreFilePath){
    get-process | where { $_.Name -like "Outlook" }| kill
    $Outlook = new-object -com outlook.application
    $Namespace = $Outlook.GetNamespace("mapi")
    $Store = $namespace.Stores | ?{$_.FilePath -like $StoreFilePath} | %{$_}
    $namespace.RemoveStore($Store.GetRootFolder())
    get-process | where { $_.Name -like "Outlook" }| kill
}

Remove-OutlookStore -StoreFilePath C:\Test\Test.pst
```