# Automate exporting public folder to PST using Outlook 2016

Tags: powershell, automation, exchange-server, devops

I'm searching for a way to automate using Outlook's Export to PST functionality in order to pull Public Folders named A-Z as individual PST files (because there is a PST size limit) and I'm hoping for a pure Powershell method.

What I have found so far isn't automated but it helped when I had to get someone's folder copied over quickly.

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

    #Get the public folder ID
     $SourceFolder = $namespace.PickFolder() | Select EntryID

#Get the destination folder ID
    $DestinationFolder = $namespace.PickFolder() | Select EntryID

    $namespace.GetFolderFromID($SourceFolder).CopyTo($DestinationFolder)
```

The second post here https://serverfault.com/questions/180916/export-exchange-public-folder-to-pst-from-powershell looked helpful but I'm running into errors with the AutoDiscover URL and/or likely permission problems.

Also found [this](https://github.com/misterGF/DevOps-PowerShell/blob/master/export-PFdata.ps1) which looked but I don't want PSTs attached to my outlook.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Copy Exchange on-prem public folder to Local Outlook PST file.
Thanks to: https://github.com/misterGF/DevOps-PowerShell/blob/master/export-PFdata.ps1
https://www.vistax64.com/threads/looping-through-outlook-folders-and-subfolders-returning-numberof-e-mails.249828/

[How to disconnect PST file from Outlook using Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058514/how-to-disconnect-pst-file-from-outlook-using-powershell)

Managed to work on this and got something functional, please use at your OWN risk. No error handling is performed.

```
function Get-MailboxFolder($folder)
 {
    Begin{
        $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
        $namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    }

    Process{
        New-Item -Path 'E:\PST.archive\Full Backup\Enterprise West' -Name "$($folder.Name)" -ItemType Directory    

        foreach ($f in $folder.folders) {

        #Location of PST files
        $PSTPath = 'E:\PST.archive\Full Backup\Enterprise West' + '\' + "$($folder.Name)"

        $PSTName = $($f.name) + '.pst'

        $FullPST = $PSTPath + '\' + $PSTName

        $namespace.AddStore("$FullPST")
        $pstFolder = $namespace.Session.Folders.GetLast()

        "Start Public Folder copy to local PST"
        [void]$f.CopyTo($pstFolder)

        }
    }#End process block

    End{
        "Removing attached PSTs from Outlook"
        $RemPST = $Outlook.Session.Stores | Where DisplayName -EQ 'Outlook Data File'

        foreach ($pst in $RemPST){
        $Outlook.Session.RemoveStore($pst.GetRootFolder())
        }
    }#end End Block
}

$WestFolders = $Outlook.Session.Folders.Item('Public Folders - YourNameHERE!!!!!').folders.item('All Public Folders').Folders.Item('Level-1').folders.item('Level-2').folders.item('Level-3')

Get-MailboxFolder $WestFolders
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no automate method to export a public folder to a PST:

Export-Mailbox command won't work with public folders.

You can do it by using:

1) use outlook : Import/Export wizard

2) use third party tools

Comment: Thanks for replying but please see my posted answer below for code I managed to get working.